# Express req body is always empty

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm trying to create a new POST method route with Express. This route will receive data in JSON. For this, i init my Express app :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.post('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers); // Correct headers from client side
  console.log(req.body); // Empty object {}
  res.status(200).send();
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${8080}!`));
```

And on client side, i send my data using `fetch` API :

```
  await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/getUsername', {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers:{
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world' })
  });
```

But my `req.body` on server side is always empty.

Is anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: are you getting anything in req.headers ?

Comment: Yes, `req.headers` return correct header from client side.

Comment: can you try to use app.use(bodyParser()) instead on first two lines and let me know

Comment: Server error : `GMT body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares`

Comment: This post says you should give bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}). https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/75ad8w/very_new_to_nodeexpress_help_with_reqbody_empty/

Comment: any luck with that?

Comment: Same result ^^ I think this params is for FormData

Comment: One more debugging questions. Can you print console.log(req) and let me know whether you can find "hello" parameter in it :)

Comment: I tested this little snippet, the express app under Postman works fine. The problem with the Content-Type header. If you set it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded you get respone body back from the the fetch request. I'm not sure about this behavior why it doesn't accept the application/json from the browser.

Comment: Arf, i've found the problem : `mode: 'no-cors',` on Headers. I've add this because i can't fetch localhost url without this parameter :(

Comment: yes, just add the cors middleware to the express app and you can fetch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 await fetch(http://localhost:8080/api/getUsername', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({hello: 'world'})
  });
```

Comment: add more description

Comment: The problem is `mode: 'no-cors',`, yes. But without this parameter, i can't fetch my localhost :(

Comment: add the cors middleware to the express app